# Type Error: 'list' object is not callable with loop

Tags: python, pandas

this is my code:

```
"Create stateyear variable"

# Set index by taking out the Area Name column and moving it to the index (the rownames)
  d3 = d3.set_index('AreaName')
# Make a list of the values in the index (Area Name)
  states_list = d3.index.values
# Make a list of the years by dropping the FIPS column, looking at the remaining columns, and taking their values
years_list = d3.drop(['FIPS'], axis = 1).columns.values

# Make empty lists to populate for values and stateyear
values = []
stateyear = []
# Start the loop with the states
for states in states_list:
# Loop through the years
for years in years_list:
    # Append the value in the state and year to the values list
    values.append(d3.loc[states, years])
    # Turn the state and year into strings, paste them together, and append to the stateyear list
    stateyear.append(str(states) + '_' + str(years))

# Make a new dataframe called stateyear_values by combining the two lists
stateyear_values = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(values, stateyear)),
                            columns = ['amount', 'stateyear'])
```

Error Message: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
9 
10 # Make a new dataframe called stateyear_values by combining the two lists
--->11 stateyear_values = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(values, stateyear)),
12                                 columns = ['amount', 'stateyear'])
13

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

This was working a minute ago, and now I'm getting that that the 'list' object is not callable. Please any help is appreciated!

Comment: tldr; don't name a variable `list` as it shadows the built-in `list` object (and it's callable construtor). I doubt that's the entire relevant (or up-to-date) code generating such an error.

Comment: Please double check your sample: some lines have been broken that shouldn't have been broken (comment lines), and indentation is missing. That makes it confusing to read.

Comment: You should also include the error, with traceback. Then we can see where the error occurs. Though I guess it is be in `pd.DataFrame(list(zip(values, stateyear)),`.

Comment: Thank you! @user2864740 and @0 0. There is no variable I have called "list", I've edited to make it clearer..

Comment: Can you make a self-contained example that we can run that reproduces the error, I don't see anything wrong by just looking at the code.